# How to make a window "Always on bottom"?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to make my window "Always on bottom", that is:

- When I minimize all windows, my window does not get minimized.
- I cannot bring it to the top of another window.

I tried to make my window a child control of the desktop window, and it worked, but I don't know if there is something wrong in doing it this way.

Comment: Cross-process relationships only work, if all involved processes are prepared for it. The desktop is not prepared for hosting a child window owned by another process. Mandatory reading: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx)

Comment: You'll want to pay attention to your uninstall program. It will be well exercised.

Comment: @David Heffernan What uninstall program?!

Comment: This sounds really unreliable.  Are you trying to make a desktop widget? If so there are better options available.  If not, can you give us some hint as to what you're trying to accomplish (ie- final result/end goal)?  Some idea of the bigger picture may give us a chance to answer this in a way that won't make Raymond Chen shake his head disapprovingly. :-)